# Word for feeling extremely embarrassed for someone else

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that evokes embarrassment in oneself through others, for example, watching a really bad performance on stage, it might not necessarily involves the humiliation of one party in public, the party can also be oblivious to what he is doing, but evokes a sense of embarrassment upon observation by someone else.

Comment: That's just another sense of _embarrassed_. One can be embarrassed for oneself or for another; the word refers to a feeling of uncomfortable social interaction, which can be experienced empathetically.

Comment: Not an *English* answer, but German has invented the very nice term "Fremdschämen", which matches your description exactly. Some dictionaries translate it as *second-hand embarrassment* or *vicarious embarrassment*.

Comment: But what if the person isn't being humiliated? It could be a person trying to hard to be sociable, or for example, a boy being too persistent in chasing a girl but does not seem to realise the situation he is in, and observing his actions evoke embarrassment in someone? @Mari-LouA

Comment: Well, edit your question explain why none of the terms suggested answer your question, and you stand a very good chance of keeping the post open. I think watching someone performing badly on stage is very similar to the situation described in the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

> [***discomfit***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/discomfit) -
>
> Make someone feel embarrassed

In this sense I like *discomfited*, though it of course it does not specifically mean for others.

Comment: You should paste the dictionary records in your answer, and then quote at the bottom of it crediting the source of the dictionary records.

Comment: @BlessedGeek This was an iPad post.  I worked had for that amount of markdown.  Not sure what's not implicit in a link and a blockquote regardless.

Comment: Bostonian accent, somewhat - I worked had. Where did I pak my care.

Comment: @BlessedGeek havad yad.

Answer (score 1):

I have two words: *empathetically embarrassed*.

*Sympathetically embarrassed* doesn't quite express the situation precisely.

When I googled "empathetically embarrassed", it came up with *Vicarious Embarrassment*:

http://abcnews.go.com/Health/MindMoodNews/vicarious-embarrassment-awkward-moments-trigger-pain-centers-brain/story?id=13366555

and "The Opposite Of Schadenfreude: Vicarious Embarrassment":

http://www.npr.org/2014/07/19/332760081/the-opposite-of-schadenfreude-vicarious-embarrassment